# JWS Application blocked by Security Setteings

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Hello i have a problem with a RCP application.

**1.**
If I start the application using the following command, the application start well. 
**C:...\jre7\bin\javaws.exe ht.tps://.../application.jnlp**

**2.**
Nevertheless, if I start the same application with the JNLP downloaded on user's computer with the following command:
**C:...\jre7\bin\javaws.exe application.jnlp**

I get this error :

*APPLICATION BLOCKED BY SECURITY SETTINGS
The Java security settings have prevented this application from running. You may change this behavior in the Java Control Panel.*

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with *Java 7 Update 51*, Java does not allow users to run applications that are **not signed** (unsigned), **self-signed** (not signed by trusted authority) or that are **missing permission attributes**.

**WORKAROUND**

- Go to the Java Control Panel (On Windows Click Start and then
  Configure Java)
- Click on the Security tab
- Click on the Edit Site List button
- Click Add in the Exception Site List window

[image: Add url to Exception Site list]

**REF:** [Why are Java applications blocked by your security settings with the latest Java?](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_blocked.xml)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunatly it doesn't work.